# Wrong image recognition on Azure Custom Vision

Tags: azure, microsoft-custom-vision

Wrong image recognition on Azure Custom Vision Service.

I have a doubt. I'm using Azure Custom Vision Service for image recognition.

I uploaded my photos and I put the coca cola tag,
I added 20 similar photos and to all I put their tag
[image]

but at the time of doing the test, I get these results.
I'm doing a test with this image.

[image]

Why does Custom Vision Service say that other soft drinks are Coca-Cola?

Do I have to do other things specifically?
Are my tags wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing about Machine Learning whether Azure or not is the sample data.

Its a probability game, from the screen shot it doesn't say its Coca-Cola, it says there is an 88.1% chance its Coca-Cola.  You can right a logic from that data saying if its not a 95% match, its not Coca-Cola.

The image recognition is only giving you information based on you parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have you uploaded only pictures of coke bottles!? If so, you should at least also give the service examples of pics which do NOT contain coke bottles. Or, if you also want to recognize Sprite, obviously upload images for that category as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Custom Vision problem, but a general learning problem.

If an infant has only seen a coke cola bottle in his/her whole life, you would not expect it to differentiate a coke bottle from a sprite bottle.